# Image not displaying when loaded from xml file in asp.net

Tags: c#, xml, image, path

I have a folder on the desktop with images. i have their paths in an xml file. when i try to use the image path the image does not appear. But when i have the image folder within my solution then its working fine. Below is my xml file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ImagesXml>
  <Ad>
<ImageUrl>~/Images/bravo_bronze.jpg</ImageUrl>
<AlternateText>Img1</AlternateText>
<ImageUrl1>~/Images/bravo_star.jpg</ImageUrl1>
<ImageUrl2>C:\Users\273714\Desktop\Certificate_images\bravo_bronze - Copy</ImageUrl2>
<ImageUrl3>C:\Users\273714\Desktop\Certificate_images\bravo_star-Copy</ImageUrl3>
<ImageUrl4>~/Images/bravo_bronze - Copy (2).jpg</ImageUrl4>

  </Ad>
 </ImagesXml>
```

I need to use the image path here

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        string file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml");
        xmldoc.Load(file);
        Image2.ImageUrl = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("ImagesXml/Ad/ImageUrl2").InnerText;
        Image1.ImageUrl = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("ImagesXml/Ad/ImageUrl3").InnerText;
     }
```

In the aspx file i hv the image tags.
Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: does the code retrive the image url from XML?Try debugging using a break point and check whether the path matches the orginal path of your image

Comment: when i debug..the imageurl is empty

Comment: seems your code is not reading the line from xml

Comment: is the path i have given is in the right format?the relative path is working but not the absolute

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to serve the images from a webpage.  They need to be hosted on the web server.  The local files paths will not work

Comment: So do i need to create images folder within the solution. Cant i keep it in C: ?